# Show that the product of the sigma-fields $F_j$ is the minimal $\sigma-$field over measurable rectangles

Tags: measure-theory

I'm reading and solving "probability and measure theory" by Robert B. Ash and I'm stuck with the following exercise:

Show that $\Pi_{j=1}^\infty\mathscr{F}_j$ is the minimal $\sigma-$field over the measurable rectangles.

the definitions are as follows:

For each $j=1,2,...$ let $(\Omega_j,\mathscr{F}_j)$ be a measurable space. If $\Omega=\Pi_{j=1}^\infty\Omega_j$ and $B^n\subset\Pi_{j=1}^n \mathscr{\Omega_j}$ we define $B_n=\{\omega\in\Omega: (\omega_1,\dots,\omega_n)\in B^n\}$. The set $B_n$ is called the cylinder with base $B^n$; the cylinder is said to be measurable if $B^n\in\Pi_{j=1}^n\mathscr{F}_j$. If $B^n=A_1\times\dots\times A_n$ where for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $A_i\in\mathscr{F}_j$ then $B_n$ is called a measurable rectangle. The minimal $\sigma-$field over the measurable cylinders is called the product of the $\sigma-$fields $\mathscr{F}_j$, written $\Pi_{j=1}^\infty\mathscr{F}_j$.

Since the measurable rectangles is a subset of the measurable cylinders, one contention is done. Is the other one I am having trouble with. I suspect it has something to do with the "good sets principle" (exposed in the book) since I'm not very good at using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: let $G_n:=\{A_1\times \ldots \times A_n\times \Omega ^{\infty }: A_k\in\mathscr{F}_k\}$, then as $G_n$ is a subset of the set of rectangles we have that $\sigma (G_n)\subset \prod_{k=1}^{\infty }\mathscr{F}_k$, therefore its enough to show that
$$
\sigma (G_n)=\left\{B^n\times \Omega ^{\infty }:B^n\in \prod_{k=1}^n \mathscr{F}_k\right\}
$$
knowing that $\prod_{k=1}^n \mathscr{F}_k:=\sigma (\{\prod_{k=1}^n A_k:A_k\in \mathscr{F}_k\})$.